# How was Sun able to buy a controlling interest in Paik Industries?

Tags: lost

Very near the end of Season 4, Sun informs her father that thanks to the very generous settlement from Oceanic, she has been able to buy a controlling share in his company.

Given that Paik is by all accounts a large, powerful company - able to intimidate and manipulate the nation's government - it seems implausible that Oceanic could pay out at least 3X the value of this company (50% X 6) without going bankrupt.

Is this a plot weakness or can it be explained?

Comment: Well, that never did make sense, but isn't it rather a minor thing to be picking on in a *whole show* of things that never made sense?

Comment: I thought that was the _point_ of this site... to ask questions about things that don't really matter, and try to find a way to make plot inconsistencies fit into the canon?

Answer (score 4):

I thought the same thing as this and my theory is....

No way would she get enough compensation alone to buy enough.

Maybe, she is part of a consortium (not seen on screen) who purchased enough of the company to be considered a controlling share. In light of her fathers treatment of her and Jin, perhaps she just wanted to be the one who bounded into her dads office to break the news to him in person. I know I would want to in her shoes :)

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, airlines are liable for damages to victims or their families under the Montreal Convention. And that amount is not anywhere close to being able to buy outright 50% of a power house South Korean company.

However for arguments sake, lets say Oceanic Airlines were extremely generous to the oceanic six and gave them all 10 million US dollars each, this would roughly be 11,332,203,300.00 South Korean WON.

If Sun's fathers company was a powerhouse as they portrayed then I doubt even that amount would be enough. She could definitely buy herself a seat in the board room with that amount however.